# How to implement notification for administrator using Rachet when user does a task?

Tags: php, codeigniter, websocket, e-commerce, phpwebsocket

This is for an eCommerce website.So requirement is administrator of the website should get alert in administrator dashboard when user does a certain task(for eg. ordering a product).I am considering using Rachet instead of repeated ajax for this purpose as that will be less heavy on the website.

Is there any other way to do the same?

How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: that question is definitely too broad in my opinion - it requires a ton of background information (what r sockets, how to handle requests, how to structure those kind of informations etc....) i would suggest- you should begin with the basics - and step forward - once you understand the concept - it should be pretty easy to implement (but as i said it doesn't make any sense to answer this question here - because you've to find some kind of tutorial wich you won't find here...)

Comment: I am a bit confused about Rachet. It's my first time with websockets.Should i use Basic Rachet or Rachet Push?I already implemented with repetitive ajax,but there is some delay sometimes.What should i do?